# Photoshop, merging both these layers so they look the same

Tags: photoshop, blending

Here is my little test image:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/851/testnb.jpg/

Basically they are two images, as you can see on the left is the 1st one and on the right the 2nd one. (and yes, I know one of the images has overlapped and "cut" off the wire)

Unfortunately my lighting was bad so I didnt get the same background color or this would have been easy.

But now that you see it, how do I make it so that it looks like it is one picture? (How do I get rid of that middle seam and get the same background color?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with this: select part one of your picture (layer) then image-->adjustments--match color then select your sorce psd (the same) and the level ! 
It's not always a great solution but give it a chance!
Or you can play araound with layer masks and layer effects

Comment: Since yours is the only answer and you are new here will chose your answer. Thanks and have a good day!